# Send SMS from jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, modem

What is the best way to programmatically send an SMS from the iPhone? Talking to the modem on `/dev/tty.debug` or using private API are options.

I want to make a command line SMS utility, and I want it to work on 3.x -> 4.x iOS.

Also I couldn't make it work with `AT+CMGF=1 & AT+CMGS="[PHONE_NUM]"\r\n[MSG]\x1A` (Talking to tty.debug, iPhone 3GS iOS 4.1).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably have a look at this project which seems to achieve what you want:

- http://code.google.com/p/iphone-sms/