# Intercept SMS on Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: api, ios4, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intercept SMS on Jailbroken iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739171/intercept-sms-on-jailbroken-iphone)

I want to intercept incoming and outgoing sms in my app for jailbroken iPhone. I need to know which API's are to be used for serving this purpose. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See also [Send SMS from jailbroken iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500014/send-sms-from-jailbroken-iphone). Apart from that, there doesn't seem to be a framework or other way to intercept SMS.

Comment: Hmmm... *"how do i intercept SMS messages"* with a username of *PsychoPath*?

Comment: Thanks DarkDust.  @Slugster ... Being funny huh!

Comment: My basic need is to fetch the message via my app as soon as it is recieved on the device.